# How can we detect that server database has changed from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsurlrequest

I am developing application in which i have to create url request when server side database is updated.Actually I am trying to make url request when its necessary.So,it will reduce number of request.I want detect that server database is changed.That can be done using push notification but i am looking if there is any other-way.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be either push or pull? I am keen to know what else is possible-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not detect from the phone when db on the server is changed. You have to make frequent request to the server to see if you have new data. This will consume the users battery and its data from the data plan.

That is why you should push from the server to the mobile devices.